# Unable to connect via SSH or access NFS exports

Tags: ssh, network-attached-storage, pam, rpc

This one has me puzzled, I've got a home server (Debian Bookworm) and several Raspberry Pi machines, also all running Raspbian Bookworm.   Just for illustrative purposes

ServerA Debian Bookworm
PI1, PI2, PI3   All machines are on the same subnet connecting through the same wifi access point with the same firewall config, and UIDs and GIDs are the same for the users across all machines

Now, I have an NFS export on ServerA

```
/mnt/NAS 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(no_root_squash,async,insecure,no_subtree_check,nohide,rw,fsid=0,crossmnt)
```

Now, Pi1 and Pi2 can access this NFS share without any problems, everything works as it should
Pi3 however, seems to mount the share.... it says its mounted,

`192.168.1.2:/mnt/NAS on /mnt/NAS type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,soft,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.1.2,mountvers=3,mountport=56271,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.2)`

and on the server side the log appears to show a successful mount

```
Dec 30 16:26:39 thindebian daemon.notice rpc.mountd[2099]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.1.104:1006 for /mnt/NAS (/mnt/NAS)
```

But if I attempt to view the directory with ls it just sits there, no error, no access denied... just seems to hang until I press CTRL-C

Now, I think somewhat related...

Same setup.... I cannot ssh from PI3 to SERVERA nor can is ssh from SERVERA to PI3
BUT... I can ssh from PI3 to PI1 and PI2 and I can SSH from PI1 or PI2 to PI3, and I can ssh from my laptop to PI3, and I can ssh from PI1 and PI2 to SERVERA.

So basically, I've confirmed that SERVERA is accepting incoming ssh connections from everything BUT PI3
PI3 is able to receive incoming ssh connections from everything BUT SERVERA
PI3 is able to make outbound ssh connections to everything BUT SERVERA

When I attempt to ssh to serverA from Pi3 the log shows the connection, nothing happens though on the Pi3 side and then the connection shows closed

```
$ ssh root@192.168.1.2
Connection closed by 192.168.1.2 port 22
```

and on the SERVERA logs it just shows

```
Dec 30 18:02:49 thindebian auth.info sshd[81994]: Connection from 192.168.1.104 port 41742 on 192.168.1.2 port 22 rdomain ""
Dec 30 18:03:54 thindebian auth.crit sshd[81843]: fatal: Timeout before authentication for 192.168.1.104 port 52798
```

If I try to connect from Pi1, it all works as it should

```
Dec 30 18:07:32 thindebian auth.info sshd[82815]: Connection from 192.168.1.3 port 41426 on 192.168.1.2 port 22 rdomain ""
Dec 30 18:07:57 thindebian auth.info sshd[82815]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.3 port 41426 ssh2
Dec 30 18:07:57 thindebian authpriv.debug sshd[82815]: pam_env(sshd:session): deprecated reading of user environment enabled
Dec 30 18:07:57 thindebian authpriv.info sshd[82815]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Dec 30 18:07:57 thindebian authpriv.info (systemd): pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Dec 30 18:07:58 thindebian auth.info sshd[82815]: Starting session: shell on pts/2 for root from 192.168.1.3 port 41426 id 0
```

I'm sorry if this is all very confusing.... I know I'm sure confused at this point.... I just cannot figure out why there appears to be a block to connectivity just between these two machines.

UPDATE:  So I didn't even think of adding -v with ssh to get debug info... when I did here's what's happening when I try to connect to Pi3 from the server.

```
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.104 [192.168.1.104] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 -2+deb12u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 -2+deb12u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.104:22 as 'john'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

And that's where it hangs.... and essentially the same thing when I try to ssh from Pi3 to Server... in either direction it hangs at expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY

I did see another thread here that showed a similar issue, and tried that solution (adjusting MTU all machines are MTU 1500) as well as specifying the MAC with

```
ssh -o MACs=hmac-sha2-256 <HOST>
```

Neither solution worked.

Comment: What does your network look like?

Comment: Is ServerA actually on 192.168.1.0/24? That address, in that range, is reserved...

Comment: that subnet... serverA is actually at 192.168.1.2

Comment: vidarlo  mostly wifi clients, I've got the NAS wired to my router, then all other devices connect via wifi.  ad blocking is done by a pi zero running pihole,   everything is on the 192.168.1.0 subnet